# How do I block all but one item type from chests?

Tags: factorio

When using the Logistics network it happens often that my robots put unusable items in chests that exist only to feed a specific assembling machine.

In train wagons you can add a filter to each inventory slot so only items of that type can be put in that wagon by placing at least a single item in the slot and pressing +. 
I've tried the same with chests (and all other combinations of modifier keys and mouse buttons).

Is there another way I can prevent items I don't want in a chest from being put in there?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a requester chest you can set the type and quantity of the items that you want to be delivered there. I've never had robots put things in there that I don't want, however if it is a storage chest then the robots will dump anything that can't go anywhere else in there, this can clog things up if you have active provider chests as opposed to passive provider chests. I have never really needed to use active provider chests so I don't run into that issue.

Comment: Your solution will work in most cases, but I don't like having requester chests as input for these particular assembly machines. 
They use bricks which I also want have a permanent stash for so I can request them when I want to create a road. 
The requester chest will receive items from the permanent stash if it is a storage or provider chest.
I'm currently using a steel chest as a permanent stash of bricks, but this prevents me from requesting them.

Comment: In that case I would have another requester chest for your brick stash that has an inserter taking them into a provider chest so your logistics robots can supply you with them when you need to make a road. If you need a lot of bricks in your stash I would expand that to have intermediate steel chests linked with inserters. I've done that when I wanted a huge buffer of coal, I had 50+ chests full of it!

Comment: I'll try it out tonight!

Comment: “another requester chest for your brick stash that has an inserter taking them into a provider chest” — That isn't reliable; it can get into a loop where robots use that provider to supply that requester, which is futile. To make this general idea work, you have to use an intermediate chest and some circuit elements so that the requester loads the intermediate chest while the provider's empty, then the intermediate is transferred into the provider while there is no demand on the requester. This is the only known way to have storage in a specific location.

Comment: You're basically running into [this problem](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/283944/how-can-i-convince-my-logistic-robots-to-maintain-depots-for-goods-i-request-for).